# Complex SQL Server Query Assistance

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that's supposed to pull all reservations from one table and then sum the `Quantity` column from a linked table. I've set a right join on the query but for some reason, it's only showing reservations that have at least one quantity record. The query below should return 4 rows, 3 with a sum of zero quantity but is only returning a single row. Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    tblReservations.Subaccount, 
    SUM(tblBilling_Detail.Quantity) 
FROM tblBilling_Detail
RIGHT JOIN tblReservations 
    ON tblBilling_Detail.Linked_Account = tblReservations.Subaccount
WHERE Usage_Start 
          BETWEEN tblReservations.Reservation_Start
          AND tblReservations.Reservation_End 
GROUP BY tblReservations.Subaccount
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data for the two tables?

Comment: Which table does `Usage_Start` come from? If it is `tblBilling_Detail` then your `where` clause is the problem. Tip: Always use an alias on _every_ column you reference from joins. It makes it easier to understand and offers some protection against schema changes.

Comment: It references tblBilling_Detail.  I updated the column but it had no affect on the query result.  I can post data but not sure how??

Comment: I should add that I also tried FULL JOIN to try and force the issue but it had no affect either.

Comment: Who is Usage_Start? A field of tblReservation or tblBilling_Detail?

Comment: It is a field in tblBilling_Detail.  Even with the WHERE clause removed, it has no affect.

Answer (score -1):

It was the WHERE clause.  All fixed.